# How to add zoom in/out to an ImageView in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, zooming, pinchzoom

I have been attempting to add a zoom in/zoom out to my ImageView in Android Studio app, so that I can pinch or double tap in order to activate the zooming in/out. Lately I tried using Zoomy library, like this:

[image]

Below is the import statement and added dependencies (I tried some other than these, with the same unfortunate result):

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any better solution? This has been bugging me for a while. I have read through different Stack Overflow solutions, watched a few videos, and still nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you have your `implementation` line in the wrong place. You might consider posting the entire Gradle file where that line appears, as text rather than as screenshots.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't think so, it's together with other dependencies: dependencies {
     ...

    implementation 'it.sephirot.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.ablanco.zoomy:zoomy:1.1.0'

}

Comment: https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage Try this library I personally have been using it works like charm

Comment: @MohammedAbidNafi thank You for Your interest in helping me. I added a required dependency, as well as a corrseponding element in xml and yet it doesn't do anything. I cannot pinch or double tap to zoom in.

Comment: Trying contacting the author about it